# Javascript: Facebook share link with different images

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

There is a slider and i want create a button which will allow share this image ( which currently active ) and link to page to Facebook.

i tried this method, but looks like facebook cache og:image

```
FB.ui({
       method: 'share_open_graph',
       action_type: 'og.shares',
       action_properties: JSON.stringify({
           object: {
               'og:url': 'https://example.com/',
               'og:title': 'test title',
               'og:description': 'test description',
               'og:image' : 'https://assets.codepen.io/1072415/amy-humphries-moOMLIZlUaM-unsplash.jpg'
           }
       })
   });
```

PS: adding a get parameters to page url still cache the image

Comment: This isn't about caching, but due to the fact that Facebook simply does not _allow_ to overwrite these parameters at share-time any more - all the data will be taken from the OG meta tags the shared URL returned. So if you want to achieve this, you will need to share _different_ URLs, that each deliver a different image in the `og:image` meta tag. So f.e. something like `https://example.com/?shareimg=1`, `https://example.com/?shareimg=2`, or with a different parameter name and value of your choice. And the `og:url` meta tag must point to those URLs including the parameter as well.

Comment: Sharing different URLs will also mean that likes of those URLs will be counted separately though, so that is something to be aware of.